Can I use IDebugControl4::ControlledOutputWide in my WinDbg extension to create a clickable link to open a URL in a web browser?
I'm making a WinDbg extension. I can use DML (debugger markup language) to output a link into the WinDbg's command window as such:
//IDebugClient* pDebugClient;
CComPtr<IDebugControl4> pDebugControl;
pDebugClient->QueryInterface(IID_PPV(pDebugControl));

pDebugControl->ControlledOutputWide(DEBUG_OUTCTL_DML, 
         DEBUG_OUTPUT_NORMAL, 
         L"This is <link cmd=\"db 0x%x\">clickable here</link>",
         address);

This will create a link, that if clicked, will run db command in WinDbg.
I'm wondering, if there's a way to create a link there that will open an arbitrary URL in a web browser?

EDIT: As suggested in the comment, if I do:
pDebugControl->ControlledOutputWide(DEBUG_OUTCTL_DML, 
         DEBUG_OUTPUT_NORMAL, 
         L"This is <link cmd=\"https://stackoverflow.com\">clickable URL</link>");

After I click it, I'm getting:
2: kd> https://stackoverflow.com
       ^ Syntax error in 'https://stackoverflow.com'

So my guess is that one possibly needs to override the "click-event". I just can't find where it is exposed?

Have you tried just writing the URL without any tags? Windbg may automatically make it clickable.

No, I mean without any tags: ControlledOutputWide("Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com")

In windbg, opening a URL using the default browser can be done with .shell -x explorer <url>, (just tested it, and it's working) so I guess you should be able to do the same using DML.

@Neitsa oh yay. Thanks. It worked! The command then becomes "This is <link cmd=\".shell -x explorer https://stackoverflow.com\">clickable URL</link>".

While at it, do you guys know how to prevent the command from being echoed to the command window after the link is clicked?

Would OR-ing the DML flag with DEBUG_OUTCTL_IGNORE (or DEBUG_OUTCTL_NOT_LOGGED) would prevent the echo? dx has an undocumented -s flag to prevent the echo, so it's implemented in the engine, but not sure how to do it in C++ :(

@Neitsa unfortunately no. DEBUG_OUTCTL_IGNORE doesn't output anything, and DEBUG_OUTCTL_NOT_LOGGED doesn't seem to have any effect. Thanks for the tip though, I need to RE what they do in that dx command with the -s switch.

How would you use it though? I just tried dx -s @$cursession.Processes.Count() and it didn't output anything.
